# How to extends multiple classes in following code

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I know that we can not extends multiple classes. Please tell me how to do that? Please Correct my code.

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment,ListActivity {

}
```

Comment: Fragment and Activities are very different beasts.  There's definitely a better way to do whatever it is that you're doing.  Are you trying to create a Fragment that contains a ListView?  Either way.... please include more context.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to display listview inside Fragment

Comment: I would look into a tutorial for using a ListView and corresponding Adapter.  Try following the tutorial, and report back with a new question if you get stuck.  As it is, this question is rather broad and the title a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend multiple classes in Activity or Fragment,
Like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, baseClass{}
```

So what you can do is to create a new java BaseClass file that extends AppCompatActivity. The MainActivity will extent only BaseClass, Like this

`public class MainActivity extends BaseClass{}`   ***//mainactivity extents baseclass***

`public class BaseClass extends AppCompatActivity{}`***//baseclass extents appcompatactivity***

The advantage is that you can implement some base functions in the BaseClass, such as Toast, checking for internet connection, etc.

Please checkout the images in case of Activity.

[MainActivity extents BaseClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFk1i.png),
[BaseClass extents AppCompatActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZdOS.png)

In Case of Fragments

[MyFragment extents BaseFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCRfJ.png),
[BaseFragment extents Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aUMK.png)

I hope it will be helpfull, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't. Java doesn't allow for multiple inheritance. What you can do is implement multiple interfaces. So if you want to make a Fragment that has a ListView in it you can do something like this:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements BaseAdapter {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JAVA does not allowed you to extends multiple classes into one class. you can use Inner class or make your 2nd class a Interface you can include multiple interface but not multiple class. Inner class would be more suitable.